# How to convert a XML into a Hash with attributes of inner tag in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hash, xml-parsing

I have a xml like this:

```
xml =
"<outtertag id='1' value='1'>
<innertag id='2' value='2'>'Inner Tag'</innertag>
<othertag id='3' value='3'>'Other Tag'</othertag>
</outtertag>"
```

When I try to convert it into a hash using `Hash.from_xml(xml)` it gives the following output which misses the attributes of innertag and othertag:

```
{"outtertag"=>{"id"=>"1", "value"=>"1", "innertag"=>"'Inner Tag'", "otherTag"=>"'Other Tag'"}}
```

How can I parse a hash with these inner attributes?

Comment: The problem has been solved by following [this](https://gist.github.com/huy/819999).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this documentation, hope you will find your answer https://gist.github.com/huy/819999